# How to add a toggle to a BASH script to start/stop a loop?

Tags: linux, bash, while-loop

I'm an trying to add a toggle to a script that contains a loop.  The toggle would be a mouse button press that would start the loop or start the loop at will.  The only way I have been able to make the toggle work correctly was to separate the toggle and action scripts.  When I attempt to join the 2, when the toggle button is hit, it does not break out of the inner loop correctly.

***Toggle Script***

```
#!/bin/bash

PIDS=`pidof -o $$ -x $0`

if [ x$PIDS != x ]
    then
    exit 0
fi

echo -e "\nToggle:"

TOGGLE=$HOME/.toggle

if [ ! -e $TOGGLE ]; then
    touch $TOGGLE
fi

echo "${TOGGLE}"

echo -e "\nMouse:"

if [[ $(xinput --list | grep "My Mouse Label 1") == *Mouse* ]]; then
    pointerLabel="My Mouse Label 1"
else
    pointerLabel="My Mouse Label 2"
fi

pointerDevice=`xinput --list --id-only "${pointerLabel}" `

echo "${pointerLabel}"

echo -e "\nKeyboard:"

keyboardLabel="My Keyboard Label"

echo "${keyboardLabel}"

keyboardDevice=`xinput --list --id-only "${keyboardLabel}" `

scan_id=1

while [ true ]
do
    state_mouse="$(xinput --query-state "${pointerDevice}")"
        if [[ "${state_mouse}" == *"button[8]=down"* ]]; then
            if [ -f ${TOGGLE} ]; then
            rm -f ${TOGGLE}
            echo "Toggle Off"
            sleep .5s
            else touch ${TOGGLE}
            echo "Toggle On"
            sleep .5s
            fi
        fi
    scan_id=`expr ${scan_id} + 1 `
done
```

***Action Script***

```
#!/bin/bash

PIDS=`pidof -o $$ -x $0`

if [ x$PIDS != x ]
    then
    exit 0
fi

TOGGLE=$HOME/.toggle

action(){
    sub_id=1

    while [[ -f ${TOGGLE} ]]
    do
        state="$(xinput --query-state "${keyboardDevice}" | grep 'down' )"

        if [ -n "${state}" ]
        then
            if [[ "${state}" == *"key[10]=down"* ]]; then
                xdotool key --clearmodifiers 1
            elif [[ "$state" == *"key[11]=down"* ]]; then
                xdotool key --clearmodifiers 2
            elif [[ "$state" == *"key[12]=down"* ]]; then
                xdotool key --clearmodifiers 3
            fi
            break
        fi
        sub_id=`expr ${sub_id} + 1 `
        sleep 1
    done
}

echo -e "\nToggle:"

echo "${TOGGLE}"

echo -e "\nMouse:"

if [[ $(xinput --list | grep "My Mouse Label 1") == *Mouse* ]]; then
    pointerLabel="My Mouse Label 1"
else
    pointerLabel="My Mouse Label 2"
fi

pointerDevice=`xinput --list --id-only "${pointerLabel}" `

echo "${pointerLabel}"

echo -e "\nKeyboard:"

keyboardLabel="My Keyboard"

echo "${keyboardLabel}"

keyboardDevice=`xinput --list --id-only "${keyboardLabel}" `

scan_id=1

while [ true ]
do
    action
    scan_id=`expr ${scan_id} + 1 `
done
```

Comment: I can't comment on the rest of the script, but the line   kill -s SIGTERM $PIDS  is counter-intuitive.  Normally you would abandon if another instance is running, NOT kill it.

Comment: I updated the kill line with your recommendation.  Thanks!  Still trying to figure out how to toggle though.

Comment: At this point, I think I've figured out a way to use a variable as a toggle (see update above), but I can't seem to nest the while loop correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to reproduce the logic of your script (with adaptations for my own desktop), *in order to understand what you are doing*.

The following script has moved your inner "while" logic as an external function, in order to clean up visibility of what is happening (for myself).

I have also slightly modified the logic within the inner while, **so that a break can be triggered by any of the matched conditions**.  I believe this is what you were looking for, in order to abandon the inner loop upon match of the second condition.

If I am wrong, please clarify your needs and I will rework the logic and code.  Please not that there are many statements that have been added in order to provide meaningful diagnostics of results at various stages in order to understand what needs to be "handled".

```
#!/bin/bash

PIDS=`pidof -o $$ -x $0`

if [ x$PIDS != x ]
    then
    exit 0
fi

action(){
    sub_id=1

    while [[ ${toggle_status} -eq 1 ]]
    do
        #state="$(xinput --query-state "${keyboardDevice}")"
        #echo -e "\n[${scan_id}/${sub_id}] state = ${state} ..." | awk '{ printf("\t\t Inner |%s\n", $0 ) ; }'
        state="$(xinput --query-state "${keyboardDevice}" | grep 'down' )"

        #if [[ "${state}" == *"key[10]=down"* ]]; then
        if [ -n "${state}" ]
        then
            if [[ "${state}" == *"key[10]=down"* ]]; then
                ### keypress = top row "1"
                echo -e "\n[${scan_id}/${sub_id}] state = ${state} ..." | grep 'down' | awk '{ printf("\n\t\t Inner_2 |%s\n", $0 ) ; }'
                echo "\t toggle= ${toggle}"
            elif [[ "$state" == *"key[11]=down"* ]]; then
                ### keypress = top row "2"
                echo -e "\n[${scan_id}/${sub_id}] state = ${state} ..." | grep 'down' | awk '{ printf("\n\t\t Inner_2 |%s\n", $0 ) ; }'
                xdotool key --clearmodifiers 2
            elif [[ "$state" == *"key[12]=down"* ]]; then
                ### keypress = top row "3"
                echo -e "\n[${scan_id}/${sub_id}] state = ${state} ..." | grep 'down' | awk '{ printf("\n\t\t Inner_2 |%s\n", $0 ) ; }'
                xdotool key --clearmodifiers 3
            fi
            break   ###  exit inner loop if condition matched
        fi
        sub_id=`expr ${sub_id} + 1 `
        sleep 1
    done
}

echo -e "\nReport of all X devices:"
xinput --list
echo ""

echo -e "\nObtain label for mouse device:"
pointerLabel=`xinput --list --name-only | grep '[Mm][Oo][Uu][Ss][Ee]' `
echo "pointerLabel = ${pointerLabel}"

echo -e "\nObtain X device for mouse:"
pointerDevice=`xinput --list --id-only "${pointerLabel}" `
echo "pointerDevice = ${pointerDevice}"

echo -e "\nObtain label for keyboard device:"
#keyboardLabel=`xinput --list --name-only | grep '[Kk][Ee][Yy][Bb][Oo][Aa][Rr][Dd]' `
keyboardLabel=`xinput --list --name-only | grep 'dakai' | grep -v 'Control' `
echo "keyboardLabel = ${keyboardLabel}"

echo -e "\nObtain X device for mouse:"
keyboardDevice=`xinput --list --id-only "${keyboardLabel}" `
echo "keyboardDevice = ${keyboardDevice}"

toggle=1        ### initial value should normally be 0, i.e. un-set
scan_id=1

while [ true ]
do
    state2="$(xinput --query-state "${pointerDevice}")"
    #state2="$(xinput --query-state "${pointerDevice}" | grep 'button\[8\]=down' )"
    #state2="$(xinput --query-state "${pointerDevice}" | grep 'button\[1\]=down' )"
    echo -e "\n[${scan_id}] state2 = ${state2} ..." | awk '{ printf("\t Outer |%s\n", $0 ) ; }'

    #if [ -n "${state2}" ]
    #if [[ "${state2}" == *"button[8]=down"* ]]
    if [[ "${state2}" == *"button[1]=down"* ]]
    then
        if [ ${toggle} -eq 1 ]
        then
            toggle_status=0
        else
            toggle_status=1
        fi
        echo ${toggle_status}
        toggle=${toggle_status}
        sleep .5s
    fi

    action

    echo "sleeping 2 sec ..." ; sleep 2
    scan_id=`expr ${scan_id} + 1 `
done
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!  Apologies for the lack of clarity on my requirement.  Here is a bit more detail:
The script should rapidly repeat keys (keys 1 - 5) or perform other functions via the xdotool while holding down keys 1 - 5.  This loop should be able to be toggled with the click of a mouse button.  In my case, it is button[8].  I think what you have provided is very close, though when I tried it on my system, the toggle didn't seem to work correctly.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have no clear picture of what you are trying to do.  Maybe a block diagram flowchart would help.

Comment: Based on your feedback, I was able to get a "frankenstein" version of what I need running wherein I run 2 separate scripts 1) a toggle script that creates and removes a "toggle" file with button[8] on the mouse, and the second an action script (this script could pretty much be anything).  Whenever I attempt to join the 2 based on your recommendations, it seems to have issues breaking out of the inner loop and returning to waiting for the "toggle" file to exist.  I have updated my original post with the 2 scripts.  If these can be joined into a single script that would be ideal.